# Как загрузить данные в sessionStorage в JS?

Tags: javascript

Помогите начинающему понять логику, как работает ключ-значение. Нужно данные закинуть в sessionStorage, с которыми потом можно работать. Например:

`var link = document.referrer; 
// закинуть данные переменной link в sessionStorage
// чтобы получилось к примеру new_link`

Comment: что значит *чтобы получилось к примеру new_link*?

Answer (score 0):

Сохранить имя - Bob

```
sessionStorage.setItem('name', 'Bob');
```

Получить имя пользователя

```
sessionStorage.getItem('name'); // "Bob"
```

Сохранить и получить реферер

```
sessionStorage.setItem('link', document.referrer);
sessionStorage.getItem('link'); // "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/"
// очистить
sessionStorage.clear();
sessionStorage.getItem('link'); // null
```

Comment: Так можно делать:
`sessionStorage.setItem('link', document.referrer);
var new_link = sessionStorage.getItem('link');`

Или **link** я могу использовать дальше в коде как переменную, в которой содержится **document.referrer** ?

Comment: Да, так и стоит использовать. Создаете переменую и записываете в нее резульнат.

Comment: Получилось, но почему то, данные которые сохранил в хранилище, не работают когда перехожу на другие страницы сайта, где тоже есть код. По идеи **sessionStorage** не перезаписуется, так же ? Я записываю в переменную значение, полученную с ->  **document.referrer**, потом вывожу в div на **странице №1**, а вот когда перехожу на  **страницу №2**, то в div уже не отображается значение **document.referrer** хотя в коде прописано отображать **document.referrer** в div. Почему тогда на **страницу №2** код не подтягивает инфу с хранилища ?

Comment: @JayMorgan https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer

Comment: *document.referrer; Вернет пустую строку, если пользователь попал на страницу напрямую (не через ссылку, а, например, через закладку). Т.к. свойство возвращает строку, это не дает вам доступ к DOM ссылающейся страницы.*